# Session exception in Asp.net website development

Tags: asp.net, session

```
  //************ Try Block ************************************//
sqlStr = "select LoginId from users where LoginID like '" + sUserName.Trim() + "' and CurrentPassword like '" + objFun.EncryptData(sPassword.Trim()) + "'";
                    string sDbUserName = objFun.RunSelectQueryAndReturnString(sqlStr);
                    if (sUserName.ToUpper().Trim() == sDbUserName.ToUpper().Trim())
                    {
                        sqlStr = "select CurrentStatus from users where LoginID like '" + sUserName.Trim() + "' and CurrentPassword like '" + objFun.EncryptData(sPassword.Trim()) + "'";
                        int iStatus = Convert.ToInt32(objFun.RunSelectQueryReturnFirstFieldOfFirstRecord(sqlStr));
                        if (iStatus != 1)
                        {
                            Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("UserName", sUserName));


                            Session["LoginID"] = sUserName;    // From this line my Code goes to Catch  Block

                        Session["LoginTime"] = DateTime.Now;
                        sqlStr = "";
                        sqlStr = "Update Users set CurrentStatus=1 where LoginID like '" + sUserName + "'";
                        objFun.RunSelectQuery(sqlStr);
                        if (Login1.RememberMeSet == true)
                        {
                            Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("UserNameHistory", Login1.UserName));
                        }
                        sqlStr = "";
                        objFun.GenerateLog("USERLOGIN", "Logged in into Website", sUserName, 2, 0);
                        Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");// ,true  );

                        //throw new Exception("Unable to redirect");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception("User is already logged in");
                    }

///****************************Catch Block********************************/

       catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Login1.FailureText = ex.Message;              
        }

Exception I got at RUNTIME:
 {System.Web.HttpException: Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the <configuration>\<system.web>\<httpModules> section in the application configuration.
   at System.Web.UI.Page.get_Session()
   at Login.Login1_Authenticate(Object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
```

Comment: Have you enabled session state as noted in the error trace? Any other things you've tried so far?

Comment: Yeah I have enabled following way:   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login" EnableSessionState="True" %>
in Login.aspx page

Comment: And you've enabled SessionStateModule or provided a custom one in web.config?

Comment: post your web config, @David W is correct

Comment: Unable to Post Web.Config in this  Comment box  But there is no any EssionStateModule in My web.Config file

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the following is present in your web.config to provide SessionState to your app:

```
<system.webServer>
       <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="Session" />
        <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```